# AllJoyn Android Unity Chat Sample not Receiving Signal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, alljoyn

I recently started using the alljoyn android sdk with Unity. I've been reading a lot of documentation lately, but I just can't figure the solution for my problem. Establishing connection between the devices is no problem, the devices connects succesfully to a session.

The problem is, when I want to sent a message, from one device to another device, through the chat app. The message that I send from device A is shown on device A, but not device B. "SendChatSignal" method is called, which calls the Signal method: `AllJoyn.QStatus status = Signal(null, currentSessionId, chatMember, payload, 0, 64);` Which returns QStatus.OK. So the signal should be broadcasted through the bus, but the SignalHandler method is never called, which I don't understand since it is registered on the bus with the following:`status = msgBus.RegisterSignalHandler(this.ChatSignalHandler, chatMember, null);`

I hope you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem which seemed to fix it was removing last 2 parameters in Signal() method call.
here is my code sample which works

```
AllJoyn.QStatus status = Signal(null,NetworkLobby.currentSessionId, chatMember, payload);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can explain my answer if you want. I actually figured it out by digging the documentation.
[link] https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/unity/class_all_joyn_unity_1_1_all_joyn_1_1_bus_object.html#a469bd0b7217f8408aa6701494222c7da